how to fix broken dependencies for freecad install on PopOS 22.04 LTS
I got the following error when trying to install freecad. How do I fix the broken dependencies? I'm using PopOS 22.04 LTS.
$ sudo apt install freecad
[sudo] password for david: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libocct-visualization-7.6 : Depends: occt-misc (= 1:7.6.3+dfsg1-8~ubuntu22.04.1) but 1:7.8.1+dfsg1-3~ubuntu22.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Do I understand this correctly that the freecad package wants (or needs) to install the libocct-visualization-7.6 package which in turn depends on 1:7.6.3+dfsg1-8~ubuntu22.04.1 being installed which in turn is not able to be installed because 1:7.8.1+dfsg1-3~ubuntu22.04.1 is already installed and needed by another application?
I used npm to get try and get more information:
$ sudo npm ls 1:7.8.1+dfsg1-3~ubuntu22.04.1
[sudo] password for david: 
/var/lib/apt/lists
└── (empty)

Does this mean that 1:7.8.1+dfsg1-3~ubuntu22.04.1 isn't being used by anything?
$ uname -a
Linux devlaptop 6.9.3-76060903-generic #202405300957~1721174657~22.04~abb7c06 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed J x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Edit:
$ sudo apt rdepends occt-misc
occt-misc
Reverse Depends:
  Breaks: libocct-foundation-dev (<< 7.6.3+dfsg1-4~)
  Recommends: science-simulations
  Replaces: libocct-foundation-dev (<< 7.6.3+dfsg1-4~)
  Breaks: libocct-foundation-dev (<< 7.6.3+dfsg1-4~)
  Depends: libocct-visualization-7.8 (= 1:7.8.1+dfsg1-3~ubuntu22.04.1)
  Depends: libocct-visualization-7.6 (= 1:7.6.3+dfsg1-8~ubuntu22.04.1)
  Replaces: libocct-foundation-dev (<< 7.6.3+dfsg1-4~)


1:7.8.1+dfsg1-3~ubuntu22.04.1 is a version, not a package name. So yes, that's not something used by anything, because it's not "something", but just a version of "something".


Do I understand this correctly that the freecad package wants (or needs) to install the libocct-visualization-7.6 package which in turn depends on 1:7.6.3+dfsg1-8~ubuntu22.04.1 being installed which in turn is not able to be installed because 1:7.8.1+dfsg1-3~ubuntu22.04.1

no, you're not reading that correctly, 1:7.6.3+dfsg1-8~ubuntu22.04.1 is just the specific version of the occt-misc package that the libocct-visualization-7.6 package depends on (and the freecad package depends on that). However, something else (maybe freecad directly) requires occt-misc in version 1:7.8.1+dfsg1-3~ubuntu22.04.1.  That is a different version, and it won't work.
You can't fix that with npm (however you think npm, the developer package manager for javascript fits in here, it doesn't have anything to do with the packages that apt needs).
So, it seems that Pop!OS 22's packaging (or its Ubuntu 22.04 import) is broken. Happens, because FreeCAD as project has lately had a few problems with dependencies (I currently can't build upstream FreeCAD because it depends on libraries so old that they can't work with my system).
The solution is probably to use a self-contained binary package of FreeCAD (I really don't like to recommend that). There's multiple sources of that, but I've mad good experiences with the Ondsel FreeCAD distribution. You can download the latest release from here (as of writing, that's 2024.2.2). Download the Ondsel-ES-{version}-Linux-{architecture}.AppImage. ({architecture} is either x86_64, if you're doing this on an Intel or AMD machine, or aarch64 if you're doing this on a 64 bit ARM laptop or workstation). After downloading, make the file executable (chmod 755 *.AppImage in the directory you downloaded it into), then run it (./Ondsel-ES-2024.2.2-Linux-x86_64.AppImage or similarly adjusted).

Why do you not like the appimage binaries?

Broken dependencies don’t happen, not without adding other repositories or trying to keep packages from previous releases (and forcing things) — the tooling used to manage packages in repositories (in Debian, Ubuntu, and derivatives) doesn’t allow inconsistent dependency sets.

@StephenKitt when you say adding other repositories are you suggesting that adding the ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable repository was a 'bad' move?

I was able to find a fix. I should probably have mentioned that I originally installed FreeCAD (v0.19.2) using the official Pop!OS repo. I then reinstalled FreeCAD (v0.21.2) using the ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable repo. I was having a few issues with that version so I tried the appimage (v0.21.2) directly from the (FreeCAD project). This was originally working until I removed the FreeCAD apt package installation:
sudo apt remove freecad
sudo apt autoremove

Then the appimage stopped working (separate issue still unresolved). So I attempted to reinstall FreeCAD (0.21.2 from ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable). That's when I got the dependency issue described here.
Ok so the fix... I reinstalled FreeCAD using the official Pop!OS repo. That installed the libocct-visualization-7.5 package and now the dependency is fixed. I was also able to install again v0.21.2 from ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable.

The FreeCAD can be installed through snap and flatpak.
Snap:
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install freecad

Flatpak:
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.freecadweb.FreeCAD
flatpak run org.freecadweb.FreeCAD

Install FreeCAD on Pop!_OS
